# how to display a image in the modal dialog with MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I create a Dialog project with MFC, also i know how to display a image in the main dialog,like the code showed below, with the showImg() function i can display a image in the main dialog.Then i create a child dialog,when i try to display one image in the child dialog with showImg() fuction, it reminds me that "Debug assertion fail!",how to show a picture in a modal dialog?someone can help me?

```
void CWeldSeam_captureDlg::showImg(Mat& mat, UINT ID)
{
    if (!mat.empty())
    {
        CDC* pDC = GetDlgItem(ID)->GetDC();
        HDC hDC = pDC->GetSafeHdc();
        IplImage img = mat;
        CvvImage cimg;
        cimg.CopyOf(&img);
        CRect rect;
        GetDlgItem(ID)->GetClientRect(&rect);
        cimg.DrawToHDC(hDC, &rect);
        ReleaseDC(pDC);
    }
}

void CWeldSeam_captureDlg::OnBnClicked_Adjust_Threshold()
{
    Mat img = imread("im2.bmp");
    showImg(img, IDC_Picture);
}
```

Comment: Change `ReleaseDC(pDC)` to `GetDlgItem(ID)->ReleaseDC(pDC)`. Get more information from debug errors.

Comment: MFC's debug assertion dialog tells you, which condition was checked and evaluated to `false`. It also has a button that takes you right to the source code, in case you need inspect the code vicinity. At the very least you should add the debug assertion message to your question (all standard dialogs support [Ctrl]+C to place a text representation of their content into the clipboard).